# How can I set an Excel Cell Value as the criteria for Access Query?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, dao

I am creating a new query in MS Access that updates an existing record based on the "Branch" and "Employee" fields. How can I set the criteria to reference cell values? Say `A2` holds the "Branch" ID for Access and `B2` holds the value for the "Employee" ID in Access.I want to update my Access "Notes" Field. My query works when running in Excel, but only because I have specified what the "Employee" & "Branch" ID's are. Nothing updates when i run my code below:

**Code**

```vb
Sub modify_record()
Dim ac As Object
Dim branchid As String
Dim employeeid As String
Dim notesF As String
Set ac = CreateObject("Access.Application")

branchid = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A2")
employeeid = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("B2")
notesF = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("C2")

Dim strDatabasePath As String
strDatabasePath = "C:\Users\johnsmith\OneDrive\pbsbackup.mdb"

With ac
.OpenCurrentDatabase (strDatabasePath)
Dim db As Object
Set db = .CurrentDb
db.Execute "Update_Records"
End With

End Sub
```

**Query in MS Access. Saved as Update_Records**

```
 UPDATE pbsmaster SET pbsmaster.notes = "notesF" WHERE 
    (((pbsmaster.branch)="branchid") AND((pbsmaster.employee)="employeeid"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables don't magically transfer into the query, just because they have the same name.

You need to specify the parameters in the Access query, and pass them via a `DAO.QueryDef` object in the Excel VBA code.

Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2317225/3820271

```vb
Dim qd As Object ' DAO.QueryDef
Set qd = db.QueryDefs("Update_Records")
qd.Parameters("branchid") = branchid
' etc.
qd.Execute
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I'll look into parameters. Still learning SQL. I'll accept once I get it working with your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution from what I learned from @Andre. I am able to execute my code, I noticed working with Parameters is much quicker than opening a recordset with DAO.

```
Sub foo()
Dim db As Database
Dim qdf As QueryDef

Set db = OpenDatabase("C:\Users\employee\OneDrive\samplefile.mdb")

Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", _
          "PARAMETERS pbsbranch text , pbsnotes text; " & _
          "UPDATE pbsmaster SET pbsmaster.notes=[pbsnotes] " & _
          "WHERE pbsmaster.branch=[pbsbranch]  " & _
          "")
qdf!pbsbranch = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A2")
qdf!pbsnotes = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("C2")

qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
Set qdf = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
End Sub
```